# Adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin to Laravel

Tags: laravel, cors

The app in question (I am simply trying to maintain/bug fix - I am not the author) (Laravel 5.1.7) needs to call JavaScript located at s7.addthis.com. This is currently not working and is returning a Cross-Origin Request Blocked error. After doing some research, I found barryvdh/laravel-cors which seems to be the preferred method for addressing this problem. However, I believe that I have followed all of the instructions, but the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not appearing in the output.

These are the steps I followed (I am a Laravel novice...):

1. composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors 0.7.x
2. composer update
3. cp vendor/barryvdh/laravel-cors/config config (did not customize)
4. Added 'Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider', to the $providers array in config/app.php
5. Added 'Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors', to the $middleware array in app/Http/kernel.php
6. php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"

The header is still not being added to the output, i.e., the errors persists. What step did I miss and/or what did I do wrong?

In an attempt to just things working, I tried adding the following to the top of bootstrap\app.php

```
// allow origin
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
// add any additional headers you need to support here
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type');
```

but this too had no effect.

I did see this post: http://en.vedovelli.com.br/2015/web-development/Laravel-5-1-enable-CORS/, which looks straight-forward enough, but in my app, the javascript is called in this manner: `{!! Html::script('//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xxx', array('async' => 'async')) !!}` and I do not know how to cast this into the form shown.

Thank you.

In response to SSahut:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    'Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors',
];
```

Comment: can you post how you add the cors in you kernel?. Mine is working perfectly with barryvdh cors

Comment: Thank you - I edited the post and added the code

Comment: I'm afraid you are confusing things here? You add CORS headers when you want to open/modify access to YOUR scripts or content, hosted on your server. You cannot have any effect over addthis.com scripts and the headers that are used for their content. Anyway, what's the task, what's the problem exactly? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you the owner of s7.addthis.com or are you trying to make an Ajax call to another api?

Comment: Denis, mimo - based on your comments, I am confused! I am trying to run a script that resides on s7.addthis.com. When the script loads, I get the following warning: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://m.addthis.com/live/... (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)`. Since the addthis 'button' is not working properly, I assumed that this is the root cause of the problem.